# Object Mapping : How do map the array object without specify the key

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I am using the below link to map the objects.

https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

I am facing the issue while mapping the `serviceids` (`Json` structure in below) array object which is without key.

Kindly help me on the if someone worked on it.

Regards,
Guddu.

Json Structure:

```
Consumer = (
   {
address = "12120 Sunset Hills Road Reston Virginia";
                clientid = 280396;
                consumerid = 280396;
                lag = 0;
                lat = 0;
                name = "William Holland";
                zipcode = 64321;
serviceids =                 (
                    5,
                    100,
                    101
    )
}
```

**In Consumer mapper class:**

```
serviceIdsArray <- map["serviceids"]
        serviceids = NSSet(array: serviceIdsArray!)
```

**In Serviceids class :**

```
func mapping(map: Map) {

        serviceid <- map[?]

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the model should be like this :

```
class JsonModel: Mappable {
var address: String?
var clientid: Int?
var consumerid: Int?
var lag: Int?
var lat: Int?
var name: String?
var zipcode: Int?
var serviceids: [Int]?
required init?(_ map: Map) {

}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    address    <- map["address"]
    clientid    <- map["clientid"]
    consumerid    <- map["consumerid"]
    lag    <- map["lag"]
    lat    <- map["lat"]
    name    <- map["name"]
    zipcode    <- map["zipcode"]
    serviceids    <- map["serviceids"]
}
}
```

then use :

```
let json =   [
        "address" : "12120 Sunset Hills Road Reston Virginia",
        "clientid" : 280396,
        "consumerid" : 280396,
        "lag" : 0,
        "lat" : 0,
        "name" : "William Holland",
        "zipcode" : 64321,
        "serviceids" :[
            5,
            100,
            101
        ]
    ]
    let model = JsonModel(JSON: son)
```

serviceids just an array,don't need to make a model for it

Comment: but here is my issue that how to set var serviceids: [Int]? in model class. It's not allow me as array of int while set the attribute in core data. and i put this manually get the crash on below line : 

serviceids    <- map["services"]

please guide on this.

Comment: you can transform [int] to NSData and store it in core data ,but it not the best way.  If I were you ，i will choose Realm to store because objectmapper provide good support for it .